# Excel - count 45 days after a date

Tags: excel, date, formula, counting, days

I have a list of varying enrollment dates. I'd like excel to calculate 45 days after the enrollment date.
Anyone know the formula for that?

Comment: Ahem... Have you googled for "Excel - count 45 days after a date" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A1`, your formula is simply `=A1+45` :-)

Comment: I had forgotten the equal sign before. Now it worked! Thanks!!